# Where is the cause of: Error Connecting to Glassfish Server?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, glassfish-3

I'm running into the following error when trying to deploy to Glassfish from IntellIJ IDEA, but I can't work out where to look first to find the issue.

```
Error running 'Glassfish Dev' 
Error Connecting to Glassfish Server. 
Exception occurred : java.lang.NullPointerException 
Exception message : null
```

This is Glassfish 3.1, the configuration used to work but has recently stopped, I can't work out if the issue should be investigated within the Glassfish server or the local project + config.

Comment: Please check idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") and Glassfish logs.

Comment: Glassfish.log is empty, nothing has been added in.

Comment: What about IDE log?